# Show that the surface area of a cone is $\pi a \sqrt {a^2+h^2}$ by considering how a sector of a disc can be folded

Tags: geometry

Show that the surface area of a cone in terms of it’s height and radius is $\pi a \sqrt {a^2+h^2}$ by considering how a sector of a disc radius r angle $\phi $ can be folded to make a cone.
I cannot reach the surface area in the requested form, only in the form $2r (2 \pi - \phi)$

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Where are you stuck? [How to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The side of the cone is the radius of the sector and the circumference of the base is the arc of this sector.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here’s a paper cone , of radius $a$ , and height $DG=h$.

By Pythagoras’ Theorem , the slant height $DF=\sqrt{a^2+h^2} $

Now , cut along $DH$ , and unravel the curved piece of paper. We obtain a circular sector .

[image]

Here , $H’$ and $H”$ both represent the same point $H$ . Therefore , we have $H’H”= 2 \pi a$ . The radius of the sector = $\sqrt{a^2+h^2} $.  $\angle H’DH” = \frac{2 \pi a}{\sqrt{a^2+h^2}} $ , as $\theta = \frac{s}{r} $ .

$\therefore $ The area of the circular sector =$ \pi r^2 \cdot \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} =  \boxed{\pi a \sqrt{a^2+h^2} }$